# How to do multiple select with ActiveCell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make multiple selections from Sheet2. The value is from the same column but different rows (thinking if using ActiveCell.Offset(1,0) will be feasible).

My code takes the value from an ActiveCell select and runs a macro compares it to another sheet (Sheet10) with some information to copy and paste in a target sheet (Sheet5).

The following is the code that I have right now.

```
a = Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
c = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0))

For i = 2 To a 'from Row 1 to the last row of "DMP"
Debug.Print ("i = " & i)

If cell.Value = Sheet10.Cells(i, 1).Value Then 'if selected cell matches (i,1) of "Sheet10 (DMP)"
    Debug.Print ("ActiveCell =" & ActiveCell.Value)

    For k = 1 To 20 'from Column 1 to Column 20
        Debug.Print ("k = " & k)

        For r = 1 To c 'from Row 1 to the last row of "Sheet 2(LightOn SKU)"
            Debug.Print ("r = " & r)

            If Sheet10.Cells(i, k).Value = Sheet2.Cells(r, 4).Value Then 'if value of (i,k) of "Sheet10 (DMP)" = (r,4) of "Sheet2 (LightOn SKU)"

                Sheet2.Range("A" & r & ":G" & r).Copy
                Sheet5.Activate
                b = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                Sheet5.Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("A" & r & ":L" & r).Borders.Color = vbBlack
             End If

        Next

    Next

End If

Next

Next
```

Right now, it's running on an endless loop.

Comment: Could you be more specific about it? What is copied in which row/column and pasted where?

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008 I've updated the code to show my full code. The copy and paste doesn't really affect what I'm asking. It's more of the selection of the active cell that will determine what's to be copied and pasted.

Comment: So, what is your problem here? I have noticed the following: Variables a and c are unknown (probably calculated in the code before this code). You have For k = 1 to 20 and you have from 6 to 30 in the comments. Sheet2's name is 'LightOn SKU' but sheet10 is at one time referred to as 'Dependency Matrix' and later as 'DMP'.Sheet5's name is unknown. The code can be optimized.

Comment: Currently, ActiveCell is only reading from one cell, but I like for it to read from multiple selections. I agree the code is not the best, it's just a fast and dirty code. I'm coding for the first time.

Comment: It is unclear on what sheet the activecell is supposed to be?

Comment: The ActiveCell is from Sheet2

Answer (score 1):

## Still Unclear

```
Sub ACCopy2()

  Dim a As Long
  Dim c As Long
  Dim r As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim k As Integer
  Dim b As Long
```

> ```
>   a = Sheet10.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
>   c = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
>
>   For r = 1 To c ' from Row 1 to the last row of "Sheet 2(LightOn SKU)"
>     Debug.Print ("r = " & r)
>     For i = 2 To a ' from Row 1 to the last row of "DMP"
>       Debug.Print ("i = " & i)
>       ' if selected cell matches (i,1) of "Sheet10 (DMP)"
>       If Sheet2.Cells(r, 1).Value = Sheet10.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
>         Debug.Print ("Sheet2 =" & Sheet2.Cells(r, 1).Value)
>         For k = 1 To 20 ' from Column 1 to Column 20
>           Debug.Print ("k = " & k)
>
>           ' if value of (i,k) of "Sheet10 (DMP)" = (r,4) of
>           ' "Sheet2 (LightOn SKU)"
>           If Sheet10.Cells(i, k).Value = Sheet2.Cells(r, 4).Value Then
>             With Sheet5
>               b = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
>               Sheet2.Range("A" & r & ":G" & r).Copy .Cells(b + 1, 1)
>               .Range("A" & r & ":L" & r).Borders.Color = vbBlack
>             End With
>           End If
>
>         Next
>       End If
>     Next
>   Next
> ```

```
End Sub
```